# Why model => model.Reason_ID turns to model =>Convert(model.Reason_ID)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, lambda

I have my own html helper extension, which I use this way

```
<%=Html.LocalizableLabelFor(model => model.Reason_ID, Register.PurchaseReason) %>
```

which declared like this.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString LocalizableLabelFor<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr, string captionValue) where T : class {
            return helper.LocalizableLabelFor(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expr), captionValue);
        }
```

but when I open it in debugger `expr.Body.ToString()` will show me  `Convert(model.Reason_ID)`. But should `model.Reason_ID`.
That's a big problem, because `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expr)` returns empty string.

What strange magic is that? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies with your Func generic types. Replace `Func<T,object>` with `Func<T,S>` and you'll be good to go:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LocalizableLabelFor<T,S>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, S>> expr, string captionValue) where T : class
{
    // ... code ...
}
```